# Ads events from Admob to BigQuery

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, admob, ads

I use ads in my app using Google Admob. My goal is to make deep analysis on my app. I linked my app with Firebase and Google Analytics. Also I connected Firebase with Admob and link Firebase to BigQuery. But I can't see full events from Admob in BigQuery. Parameters I want to see per event is at least user_id, screen_name and ad_id. It would be great if I also will see how much money I receive from every ad shown. I know that this data is shown in Firebase and Google Analytics, but it shown in very general way, my goal is to investiagete it deeper.

Thanks!

Scheme
[image]

Received event example
[image]

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same thing. But haven't found a way. Only thing I found out is that ad events are not sent to bigquery. See here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en&visit_id=638029270880600571-1343506868&rd=1